# Using the UPDATE statement in SAS to carry forward the last observation by group

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with observations of patients and their diagnoses at multiple points in time. The values of the dummy variables for diagnosis are sometimes missing. Here is an example:

```
  data have ;
    infile datalines dsd delimiter=' '; 
    input patient $ year $ K50 $ K51 $ K52 $ ;
    datalines;
    1 2010 . . .
    1 2011 . 1 .
    1 2012 . 1 1
    1 2014 . . .
    2 2009 1 . .
    2 2010 . . .
    2 2013 . 1 .
    2 2015 . . .
    ;
    run;
```

If the values of the dummy variables are missing in the current observation, I want to carry forward the values of the dummy variables in the previous observation, provided that the patient ID is the same. To achieve this, I have experimented with the following code:

```
data master_dt;
if 0 then set have;
if 1 then delete;
run;

data master_dt;
update master_dt have;
by patient;
output;
run;
```

Unfortunately, the code above does not achieve quite what I am looking for. It carries forward the value of a dummy variable to the next observation if the value of that variable is missing in the next observation, regardless of whether any of the other variables in the observation are present. I only want to carry forward values when all dummy values are missing in the next observation.

Any ideas how I can modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: You've assigned the variables year, k50-k52 as character, which means that a period (.) will be stored rather than a missing value.  Is this intentional, or should they be numeric variables (as I suspect)

Comment: You are right; they should be numeric.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Can you give an example where the value you want is different than what UPDATE would do? For example what values do you want for the next to last observation?

Comment: If you look at the observations of patient 2, the update statement would carry forward a value of 1 in the K50 column through all of the subsequent observations of that patient. I want to carry forward the value only as long as there is no value in any of the other columns (in this case, K51 and K52). This means that observations 1 and 2 of patient 2 should have a 1 in the K50 column, and that observations 3 and 4 of the same patient should have a 1 in the K51 column. With my current code, obs 3 and 4 of patient 2 have a 1 in column K50.

Answer (score 0):

Data set options.  Your data set to create master with 0 obs is not needed.  Also you INFILE statement in data have is unnecessary and causing problems.

```
data have ;
    input patient $ year $ K50 $ K51 $ K52 $ ;
    datalines;
    1 2010 . . .
    1 2011 . 1 .
    1 2012 . 1 1
    1 2014 . . .
    2 2009 1 . .
    2 2010 . . .
    2 2013 . 1 .
    2 2015 . . .
    ;
    run;
proc print;
   run;
data want;
   if 0 then set have;
   update have(obs=0 keep=patient) have(drop=year);
   by patient;
   set have(keep=year);
   output;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

So if want the missing values to overwrite the previous values you need to make them have the special missing value of `._`.

```
data fix_missing ;
  set have ;
  array x k50-k52  ;
  if 0 < N(of x(*)) < dim(x) then do _n_=1 to dim(x);
    if x(_n_)=. then x(_n_)=._;
  end;
run;

data want;
  update have(obs=0) fix_missing;
  by patient;
  output;
run;
```

Which yields this list of values:

```
1 2010 . . .
1 2011 . 1 .
1 2012 . 1 1
1 2014 . 1 1
2 2009 1 . .
2 2010 1 . .
2 2013 . 1 .
2 2015 . 1 .
```